# how can i call the same asynchronous function multiple times (synchronously) using a loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, callback

I have a an array called "products" that varies on each page load. I then need to call a function "addProduct()" for as many times as "products" is long, and use an altered value of each index inside that function. The function is long a complex and uses asynchronous calls (like .get) How can I stop the for loop from going to the next iteration until addProduct() is finished executing?

```
 function addProduct(productVariable){

      // (...do some long and asynchronous things with productVariable...)
 }

 //products array can vary in length on each page load
 products = ["prod01","prod02","prod03","prod04","prod05",...];

 for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

      var productAlter = product[i];

      //(...do some things with productAlter, but wait 
      // until the previous loop's addProduct() function 
      // has completed successfully)

      addProduct(productAlter);
 }
```

I keep reading about callbacks and promises, but no matter when I put them, the function seems to fire asynchronously. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a recursive function that after finishing the asynchronous actions calls itself with a global counter to iterate over all products. I'm on my phone so writing code is too hard.

Comment: Try look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Techniques/Promises).

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo thanks Alvaro, this is likely what i'd be looking for. When you have a moment to jot out some notes it would be much appreciated...thx!

Comment: My idea was almost exactly what @mohamed-ibrahim answered.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo ok great thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will make use of success callback for Ajax to call `addNextProdut` and if the index reach its max then it will stop.

```
function addProduct(productVariable){
  $.ajax({
   url: your_action_server_url,
   context: document.body,
   success: function(){
     addNextProduct()
   }
   })
 }

 function addNextProduct(){
    index++; 
    if(index < products.length)
      addProduct(products[index])
 } 

 products = ["prod01","prod02","prod03","prod04","prod05",...];
 index = 0;
 addProduct(products[index])
```

Comment: Thanks @mohamed-ibrahim . If you wouldn't mind clarifying this scenario.. what would go into test.html?

Comment: sorry that was an example, you should repalce it with your url